# should i ignore warnings

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should i ignore all the warnings while building some project in ros and only remove the errors? For example while building a project i get below yellow colourd warnings:

```
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/src/gmock/CMakeLists.txt:40 (project):
  Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:

    PROJECT_VERSION
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
    
    CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/src/gtest/CMakeLists.txt:42 (project):
      Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
      Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
      command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:

    PROJECT_VERSION
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Will not this type of warnings create bug latter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286095/should-i-ignore-warnings/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-21**:
Similar [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/222139/how-to-disable-policy-cmp0045-is-not-set-warnings/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Warnings are usually there for a reason. You should not just ignore them outright. They usually can mean that you're doing something that might be a problem. They will help you write cleaner code.

This is really a more general topic than ROS so I'd suggest that you look at external resources. Here are a few resources I found quickly:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512222/is-it-a-good-idea-to-eliminate-compiler-warnings
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94754/how-do-i-convince-my-teammates-that-we-should-not-ignore-compiler-warnings/94756
- https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/compiler_warnings.html
- https://arne-mertz.de/2016/02/compiler-warnings-treat-them-right/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is good practice to deal with all warnings and end up with a squeaky clean build. Sometimes warnings like for a "narrowing conversion" may indicate bugs in your code. The warnings you specify here seem to be benign and you can suppress them by adding `-Wno-dev` to your build flags as the message says.

---

Originally posted by [JamesGiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/34047/jamesgiller/) with karma: 229 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1